# Что значит в питоне " |= "?

Tags: python

Что значит в питоне оператор `|=`?

Comment: `var |= value` тоже самое что `var = var | value`

Comment: Спасибо, а | это получается or?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.ior

Comment: @Katepl Да - или равно.

Comment: `|` для чисел это OR, для других типов данных может быть и другая операция

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это `|` проведено на месте. `a |= b` в основном эквивалентно `a = a | b` .
`|=`- это так называемый расширенный оператор присваивания . Его цель состоит в том, чтобы выполнить операцию на месте или операцию, как и обычная операция `|` .

Есть, однако, некоторые отличия, так как вызывается другой метод объекта: для `|` это **or**() или **ror**() , для `|=` это **ior**() .

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Дух сообщества, мой ответ вообще-то приняли, значит он отвечает на заданный вопрос)))

Comment: @Eclipse рядом с ником стоит, что `Дух` - это всего лишь бот. А появился данный комментарий от отдного из членов сообщества с рейтингом, который позволяет от имени данного бота при проверках оставлять такие сообщения. Здесь имеется в виду, что при ответе на вопрос можно оставлять ссылки на источники или актуальную на данный момент документацию. Хорошо прописанный ответ дает как вам профит в виде выученного/повторенного, так и тем, кто будет искать ответ. [Дух здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%d0%94%d1%83%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: @Dmitry, я понял что это бот. А смысл мне оставлять ссылки, если я прописал всю информацию?

Answer (score 3):

`a |= b` тоже самое, что и `a = a | b`, где `|` - операция [побитового ИЛИ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F#:%7E:text=0001-,%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%98,%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2.).

Comment: Не обязательно побитовое ИЛИ, это может быть union для set или update для dict например.